# Android Progress Dialog Set Message From a Class File

Tags: android, message, progressdialog

I have the following code that downloads a video using AsyncTask.

```
//DOWNLOAD VIDEOS
private class downloadVideosAsync extends AsyncTask <String, String, String>{

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        MyActivity.this.mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading Videos...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings){
        try{

            VideosC.downloadVideos( VideosM.getVideoNames(), VideosM.getVideoUrls(), 
                                    VideosM.getVideoThumbs(), VideosM.getFileModified() );

        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String lenghtOfFile) {
        new downloadSlideshowsAsync().execute();
    }
}
```

As you can see I have set the message "Downloading Videos..." for my progress dialog. Now what I want to do is something like setMessage("Downloading 1 of 5"). But the problem is my downloadVideos function is in another class file VideosController.java

```
public void downloadVideos( ArrayList<String> VideoNames, ArrayList<String> VideoUrls,
                                ArrayList<String> VideoThumbs, ArrayList<String> fileModified){

    try{
        int x;
        int videoNamesLenght = VideoNames.size();
        File vidFile;
        for(x = 0; x < videoNamesLenght; x++) {

            String[] videoName = VideoNames.get(x).split("/");
            String currentFile = videoName[0] + "." + videoName[1];
            String currentFileURL = VideoUrls.get(x) + VideoNames.get(x);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "currentFileURL: " + currentFileURL);

            vidFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
                                + "/MyApp/Downloads/Videos/", currentFile);

                    //I want to do maybe here something like
                    //mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading x of y")

            downloadVideoFile(currentFile, currentFileURL, vidFile, fileModified.get(x));

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a static function in Activity which call the VideosController.
In that function you can send Handler Message and handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your response @rafeal piao, but do you have a sample code for it, im actually a beginner. :)

Comment: Sorry I not have any sample in my hand.

Comment: When call VideosController, you can pass the Context Object. From the Context you can visit the static Function, Please set this code in  onPostExecute method.